# Oracle: In Operator for null values?

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have two tables A and B which have the exact same columns. I want to write a query that selects all rows from A that also exist in B, so I would want to write something like:

```
select att1, att2, att3 from A 
where (att1, att2, att3) in (select att1, att2, att3 from B)
```

However, this does not work when my tables are allowed to contain null values, as the `in` operator checks equality using `=`, so for example `att1 = att1`. This won't work on null values as `null = ...` always results in false.

Whats the best/easiest way to do the same thing as the query above but that also works when there are null values (returns true if the 2 compared attributes are null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `INTERSECT` set operator, instead?

```
select att1, att2, att3 from A 
intersect
select att1, att2, att3 from B
```

Comment: thank you, this works. Another question: Is there a way to use this in a DELETE statement? So delete all from A that also exist in B ?

Comment: DELETE a.*, b.*  
FROM table1 as a, table2 as b  
WHERE (A.ATT1, A.ATT2, A.ATT3) IN (select att1, att2, att3 from A 
intersect
select att1, att2, att3 from B);

Comment: @Krise . . . Note that this doesn't do *exactly* what you are requesting, because `INTERSECT` removes duplicates.  That said, it is probably what you want, but worth pointing out.